# EXCEL: FORMAT a "jan" "feb" "mar" "apr" into a MONTH ( 01,02,03)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please anybody know:

```
Date----------------Result--------------------------------------What I want!
9.99 LATE AUG 13 ---IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("aug",B2&" "&C2)),"08"---08
9.99 Early Sept 13 ----"""--------------------------------------09
```

---

if i use for all 12mnths then its gives error:-**the specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more levels of nesting than are allowed**

for eg:-

```
  (B2)------------------(C2)
```

HK-753F(6)LATE AUG 13-------     MERC

HK-754F(6)     ------------------------          EARLY SEPT 13

11.99      --------------------------------              LATE SEPT 13

11.99  --------------------------------                  LATE SEPT 13

10.99 JUNE 13  ---------------------          MERC

Comment: What is the format of the other cells you have? And why did you concatenate B2 and C2?

Comment: its occurrence possible in B2 and C2. other cell format given question

Comment: Okay. Is it always `9.99 Late` or `9.99 Early`? And when you say it can be in B2 and C2, can there be text in both?

Comment: no sometimes its look like **HK-753F(6) LATE AUG 13** both(B2 and C2) have text but "jan" "feb" is only in one cell both of them.

Comment: @Sandy Edit your post and give us some decent examples which include all your cases, instead of this back-and forth commenting.

Comment: i have added it as a example. @JanDoggen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this formula

`=MATCH(2^15,SEARCH({"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"},B2&" "&C2))`

or a slightly shorter but less transparent version....

`=MATCH(2^15,SEARCH(TEXT(29*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},"mmm"),B2&" "&C2))`

**Explanation**

When you do a `SEARCH` for an "array" of terms like {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"} then result is also an array, a #VALUE! error for each term that doesn't exist in B2&" "&C2 and a number (the position) if it does, so if B2&" "&C2 = **HK-753F(6)LATE AUG 13 MERC** then the result of

`=SEARCH({"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"},B2&" "&C2)`

is the following array:

`{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,17,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`

Note that all entries are errors except for 17 at position 8 (17 is the position of the "A" of "AUG" in B2&" "&C2).

When `MATCH` function (with no 3rd argument) looks up a "bignum" like 2^15 in that array it always matches with the last number so the result is 8 (because "aug" is 8th in the list of months)

Comment: Thanks it works but i need "01" "02" format not a "1","2". have you any resolve point for first one formula.

Comment: @saNdy You can wrap it around a `TEXT()` like this: `=TEXT(MATCH(2^15,SEARCH(TEXT(29*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},"mmm"),B2&" "&C2)),"00")`

Comment: **=MATCH(2^15,SEARCH({"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"},B2&" "&C2))** in that one please.

Comment: @saNdy It's basically the same thing: `=TEXT(MATCH(2^15,SEARCH({"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"},B2&" "&C2)),"00")`

Comment: Thanks @jerry you are very helpful for me in that issue. Actually am the beginner in that. Thanks again.

Comment: @barry houdini This is wonderful. I wonder if it would be appropriate to explain what is happening.

Comment: @datatoo, I was on my way out of the door when I posted my answer so I didn't have much time - I can post an explanation.......

Comment: @barry houdini Can't thanks you enough for the explanation of the match portion of this. Of course....should have realized